# Display mysql lines as individual td's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Question: Suppose I have the following data in my sql cell

> "line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3"

How can I display that via php to result in the following:

> <td>line 1</td><td>line 2</td><td>line
>   3</td>.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Better question, why are you putting tabular data into a single column rather than separating it all out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as that

```
$string = "line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3";
$arr = explode('<br>', $string);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
// or you can put this to some other string $otherString .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lines = "line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3";

$arr = explode("<br>", $lines);

foreach($arr as $r)
{
   print("<td>$r</td>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "<td>" . implode("</td><td>", explode("<br>", $lines)) . "</td>";
```

Not as easy to read, but avoids a loop, which is never bad! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3";
$arr = explode('<br>', $string);
$result = '<td>'.implode('</td><td>', $arr).'</td>';
```